# Marketing Cloud Available entities to Synchronized is empty

Tags: marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi

When trying to set up object, no items are showing to synchronize, is that something I've missed in the configuration

- the system user has the two appropriate roles and the Salesforce.com Status

Thanks !

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong with my connector, I forgot to create a permission set and add it to the System user, and in the connected apps.
Now, i can see my CRM objects clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Can we decide which objects to show on the available entities? like I want to restrict all objects except accounts, contacts and leads from being available - is there a wayout?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/172409)